# Manipulating double integrals to find expected value of product of independent random variables

Tags: probability, integration

Let X, Y be two independent random continuous variables, that is:

$$
f(x, y) = f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)
$$

where $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are their respective marginal density functions.

I've read a lot of times that the expected value of the product of these variables is the product of their expected values, that is

$$
E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)
$$

I would like to find a demonstration of this fact that didn't involve the Law of Total Expectation. For example:

$$
\begin{align}
E(XY) &=\iint_D x\cdot y \cdot f(x, y) \;dy\;dx\\
      &=\iint_D x\cdot y \cdot f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(y) \;dy\;dx\\
&= \dots \\
&= \int_D x \cdot f_X(x)\;dx \int_D y \cdot f_Y(y)\;dy\\
&= E(X)E(Y)
\end{align}
$$

What properties of double integrals am I missing to fill the gap?

Comment: Observe that $\int k~g(x) \operatorname d x = k~\int g(x)\operatorname d x$ where the integral's bound variable, $x$, does not occur in $k$. Then you can 'extract' the inner integral.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamKemp, your comment let me fill in the blank. It seems so obvious now... I guess taking the Probability course too much time after the Calculus one has its disadvantages...